# leave event for textbox in asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm looking for a solution for the textbox leave event in asp.net vb.net.
 I have searched but Didn't get the right solution,  what I'm actually doing is.

I have `textbox` in which a user write the `Product Id` number however the focus moved from the `textbox` then all the related data should be displayed on the concern `textboxes`.

Comment: try `textbox_lostfocus` event or `textbox_keydown` (if your using keydown event must allow after entering `enter` or 'any other key ')

Comment: can you do it in javascript?

Comment: Winged Panther, thanks for your reply but in asp.net vb.net don't have lostfocus event. then how possibly I can do that? and Using javascript I can do only basic code like copying one textbox data to another. But as far as my concern my logic is a server side, but I really dunno how to integrate server side code with Javascript. and at last  logixologist thank you to you too.

Comment: How about binding the textbox to an an object using a bindingsource and then firing in the object's 'propertychanged' event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no `textbox_lostfocus` event or `textbox_keydown` event available in `ASP.Net`. You can do the same by writing the code in `TextChanged` event of the **Text Box.**
Your code will be like the following :

```
  Private Sub txtamount_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtamount.TextChanged
   //Your code comes here
   MsgBox(txtamount.Text)// sample display
  End Sub
```

This code will give result only when you add `AutoPostBack ="true"` with your Textbox design.

ie., the ASP code for the textbox will be :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtamount" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true"  />
```

Hope that this is actually your are asking for.

Comment: Thank you so much all for the reply.